# Как получить значение атрибута

Tags: веб-программирование, тестирование, xpath, jmeter

Нужно вытянуть значение атрибута alt. Делаю через XPath Extractor выводит все элементы с пустым значением (Jmeter)

```
//img[@alt]
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильное [XPath выражение](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) `//img/@alt`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и лучше использовать [XPath2 Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-xpath2-extractor-how-to-achieve-better-correlations/), он мощнее и быстрее работает